# Taylor Series representation of $f(x) = \sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ at $a=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the Taylor Series representation of $f(x)= \sqrt x + \frac1{\sqrt x}$ at $a = 1.$ With $5$ terms.

I know how to get the series expansion. centered at $a=1$. with $5$ terms… However I can't figure out how to get the series representation.

I know that the $\sqrt x$ Taylor Series is — $(x-1)^n/n!$

Comment: You need to explain your question better.  You know how to get the 5 terms, but you don’t know how to get the series of 5 terms?  It almost sounds like you’re saying you can’t figure out how to add :).  Surely you mean something else.

Comment: I'm trying to get the Taylor Series representation. I know how to get the expansion using 5 terms but the question is asking for the representation!

Comment: “ I know that the $\sqrt x$ Taylor Series is --- $(x-1)^n/n!$” This is wrong. Not clear what you mean to say here, but this is inaccurate.

Comment: It’s also unclear what you mean by “series presentation.” If you know how to get the series expansion, how is that different from the series representation?

Comment: @supersyd As far as I can tell, the two terms are interchangeable.  What is missing that you need to get a Taylor representation?  Is your question really just “what’s the difference between the two concepts?”.  If yes, please state so clearly because it has nothing to do with this particular function.

Comment: Simply add both series with the same index for $x^{1/2}$ and $x^{-1/2}$. Use the binomial series for both.

Answer (score 1):

The first five terms are:

$$\begin{align}f(1)&+\frac{f’(1)}{1!}(x-1)^1\\&+\frac{f’’(1)}{2!}(x-1)^2\\&+\frac{f’’’(1)}{3!}(x-1)^3\\&+\frac{f’’’’(1)}{4!}(x-1)^4\end{align}$$

So you just need to compute the $f(1),f’(1),\dots, f’’’’(1).$