# Find the power series for $\ln(9-4x^2)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am trying to get the power series for $\ln(9-4x^2)$

The first step I took was taking the derivative of $\ln(9-4x^2)$
which I got: $\frac{-8x}{9-4x^2}$

Getting this into the form of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^n$ = $\frac{a}{1-r}$ is where I am having issues.

Comment: You are after a power series centered at which point?

Comment: I mean first try to finish [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4132061/688539)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are interested in a power series centered at $0$, note that\begin{align}-\frac{8x}{9-4x^2}&=-\frac{8x}9\times\frac1{1-\frac49x^2}\\&=-\frac{8x}9\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac49\right)^nx^{2n}\text{ (if $|x|<\frac32$)}\\&=-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac49\right)^nx^{2n+1}.\end{align}Therefore, the power series that you are after is$$\log(9)-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(4/9)^n}{2n+2}x^{2n+2}=\log(9)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(4/9)^n}{n+1}x^{2n+2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(9-4x^2)=\ln9+\ln\left(1-\dfrac{4x^2}9\right)$$

Now use $$\ln(1-y)=-\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}r$$ for $-1\le y<1$

Use

[What is the correct radius of convergence for $\ln(1+x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356517/what-is-the-correct-radius-of-convergence-for-ln1x)